# Angular Interceptor returns observable that doesn't emit values

Tags: angular

I wanted to use the angular interceptor in order to cache http responses in localstorage following the example from the official angular page (https://angular.io/guide/http#using-interceptors-for-caching) Here is my interceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class CachingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private cache: RequestCache,
    private store: Store,
    private notifs: NotificationsService
  ) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ):Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (req.method == "POST" || req.method == "PUT") return next.handle(req);

    let cachedObject = this.cache.get(req); //get the cached response
    const response: HttpResponse<any> = cachedObject?.response; 
    const expired: boolean = cachedObject?.expired;

    if (response && !expired) return of(response);
    else return this.sendRequest(req, next, this.cache, response);
  }

 private sendRequest(
   req: HttpRequest<any>,
   next: HttpHandler,
   cache: RequestCache,
   cachedResp?: HttpResponse<any>
 ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
   
   return next.handle(req).pipe(
     tap((event) => {
       if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
         if (req.method == "GET" && event.status == 200) cache.put(req, event); 
       }
     }),
     catchError((err) => this.handleError(err, cachedResp))
   );
 }
```

}

I can log the cached response inside of this function and also subscribe to `of(response)` inside of the intercept function and get the cached response.
However, when subscribing to the http service, which got intercepted, I get no values.

Here is the cache service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class RequestCache {

  put(req: HttpRequest<any>, response: HttpResponse<any>): void {
    const url = req.urlWithParams;
    const entry = { response, fetched: Date.now() };
    
    localStorage.setItem(url, JSON.stringify(entry));     
  }

 
  get(
    req: HttpRequest<any>
  ): { response: HttpResponse<any>; expired: boolean } | undefined {
    const url = req.urlWithParams;

    let cached = localStorage.getItem(url);
    if (!cached) return; 

    let cacheObject = JSON.parse(cached); 
    const isExpired = cacheObject.fetched < Date.now() - maxAge;

    return { response: cacheObject.response, expired: isExpired };
  }

  
}
```